# Xamarin IDE and visualstudio for windows +Mvvmcross

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

I have some confusions About the IDE to use for MvvmCross

a) VisualStudio (VS) uses Xamrarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android plugin for iOS and Android development. But can we also use PCL(Portable Class libraries) and MVVMCross/Monocross frameworks in VS? I see the PCL option on VS but, i don't see the support for Android & iOS. Do i need to install additional plugin for PCL to support these two platforms as well?

b) Xamarin IDE supports Android and iOS development on Mac but, is it true that Xamarin doesn't support Mono.iOS on windows? Isn't it strange that Visual studio can use the network mac for iOS development but why not Xamarin Studio?
Thank You for your time.

Regards,

Saurav

Comment: please try to ask one question at a time - it's better for stackoverflow and for search. If you want to ask multiple questions, use multiple questions or switch to a forum like xamarin. I'll edit your question down to the first question for now. Thanks :)

Comment: if you need to see the text I removed - to create a new question, please see it on http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16560681/revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) VisualStudio (VS) uses Xamrarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android plugin for iOS and Android development. But can we also use PCL(Portable Class libraries) and MVVMCross/Monocross frameworks in VS? I see the PCL option on VS but, i don't see the support for Android & iOS. Do i need to install additional plugin for PCL to support these two platforms as well?

MvvmCross currently uses `Profile104` for Portable Class Library development. You can easily develop for this profile without installing Android and iOS. The mapping of PCL profile to platforms is, however, quite confusing (it's not exactly obvious) so the easiest way I find to create a `Profile104` PCL is:

- to create any PCL
- then to manually edit the csproj file to say Profile104 - look for a line like: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Babel/Babel.Core/Babel.Core.csproj#L14 in the csproj

I have customers who develop in medium size teams where only some people have the Xamarin tools installed - most people have just Windows tools and work on the PCLs using Unit Tests and using WindowsPhone/Store user interfaces.

> b) Xamarin IDE supports Android and iOS development on Mac but, is it true that Xamarin doesn't support Mono.iOS on windows?

Yes, this is true.

> Isn't it strange that Visual studio can use the network mac for iOS development but why not Xamarin Studio?

This may feel strange, but I believe this is actually this is Xamarin listening to their customers.

I believe, that the reason customers wanted Windows support for iOS was because they wanted to use Visual Studio and they wanted to use plugins like Resharper. Xamarin provided this in their 2.0 release.

It is true that they could also have added iOS functionality to XamarinStudio for Windows as well - but this (I believe) wasn't what any of their customers were asking for - so adding it would have created more work (both in creating and maintaining it) without adding any significant benefit (IMO)

Comment: And build-to-simulator is much slower than directly from the mac machine. So the benefits using VS need to outweight this. (BTW they really do using Resharper). So for iOS from Xamarin Studio there are not many benefits, you need to have a mac anyway.