# couldn't install xamarin in visual studio express 2013

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

I'm running Windows 7 professional, installed `Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013`. Now, I got to work with development of android applications in `c#` and I want to do it in `Visual studio Express edition`. I found `Xamarin` would integrate android and iOS application development with c# and Visual Studio. I installed `xamarin for visual studio` [here](http://xamarin.com/visual-studio)

I tried to integrate Xamarin in Visual Studio, but couldn't succeed with it.

I followed the developer.Xamarin instructions, couldn't find `xamarin` panel in `tools -> options` (in the BUILD host settings).

Instructions [here](http://blog.fire-development.com/2013/07/01/install-xamarin-in-vs-2013-preview-1/), shows the integration of xamarin through migration from visual studio 12 to visual studio 13. I think it's out of my point from my concern.

I find some of the questions in `stackoverflow` are quite similar, though they were marked as answered but I'm sure there might be some other best solutions.

[monotouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594118/install-xamarin-for-visual-studio-2013-express), [visual studio - Xamarin IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560681/xamarin-ide-and-visualstudio-for-windows-mvvmcross?rq=1) are some of the posts that I found uninformative. I couldn't get any conclusion from those posts. I'm truly disappointed with the posts(spent lot of time, but my issue was not solved). Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: for xamarin developer instructions http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/

Comment: it was not clearly explained @hichris123

Comment: @hichris123 please go through the link https://xamarin.com/visual-studio : it is quite clear that xamarin can be installed within visual studio express 2013.

Comment: I don not see Express mentioned anywhere on that page.

Comment: ok. Is there any way to instal Xamarin with express

Comment: NO.  VS Express does NOT support any plug-ins or add-ins.  For Xamarin Android development you can use Xamarin Studio on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio Express does not support plug-ins and cannot be used with Xamarin.

> What are the minimum system requirements?
>
> Xamarin requires the platform SDKs from Apple and Google to target iOS
>   or Android, and our system requirements match theirs. To build for
>   iOS, you'll need the latest iOS SDK (currently iOS 7), which requires
>   an Intel-based Mac running OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion). Our Visual
>   Studio Extensions for iOS and Android support any **[non-Express editions
>   of Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013](https://xamarin.com/faq)**.

Comment: so, do you say that xamarin couldn't be installed within visual studio

Comment: With Visual Studio yes, with VS Express no. If you can't get the full version then you should use Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Express --> Free but no plug-ins, so no Xamarin
Visual Studio --> expensive but plug-in support

these look the same but are very different products.